# Extract groups of items with same values from javaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of nested arrays containing coordinates. I would like to create a new array containing nested arrays of coordinates based on if they have the same latitude. 
The description might be a little confusing, so here some examples and code

Initial array (latitude is the second value of the number pairs)

```js
const coordinateArray = [[46,11], [38,11], [44,9], [81,15], [55,15]];
```

Expected outcome:

```js
const newArray = [
                  [[46,11],[38,11]],
                  [[81,15],[55,15]], 
                  [[44,9]]
                 ];
```

I tried this, but it returns every coordinate in a new array instead of pairing the ones with same latitude:

```js
const rowArrays = [];
coordinateArray.map(c => {
    const row = [c];
    for (let i = 0; i < coordinateArray.length; i++) {
      console.log(c[1], coordinateArray[i][1]);
      if (c[1] === [1]) {
        row.push(coordinateArray[i]);
        coordinateArray.splice(0, 1);
      }
    }
    return rowArrays.push(row);
  });
```

Would be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map and group:

```js
const coordinateArray = [[46,11], [38,11], [44,9], [81,15], [55,15]];
let map = coordinateArray.reduce((map,coord)=>{
  map.has(coord[1]) ? map.get(coord[1]).push(coord) : map.set(coord[1], [coord]);
  return map;
},new Map())
console.info([...map.values()])
```

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is close, but as you mentioned, it unconditionally creates a new array with each iteration through `coordinateArray`. Because your input-to-output is not 1:1 and instead you're looking to change the shape, `reduce` would be preferable to `map`.

If you [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)d the array into an object based on the latitude, you could then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)  to achieve the result in your desired shape.

```js
const coordinateArray = [[46,11], [38,11], [44,9], [81,15], [55,15]];
const matched = coordinateArray.reduce((out,arr) => {
  out[arr[1]] = out[arr[1]] //Have we already seen this latitude?
    ? [arr, ...out[arr[1]]] //Yes: Add the current coordinates to that array
    : [arr];                //No: Start a new array with current coordinates
  return out;
  }, {});

//const matched looks like this:
//{
//  "9":  [[44,9]],
//  "11": [[38,11],[46,11]],
//  "15": [[55,15],[81,15]]
//}
  
console.log(Object.values(matched)); //We only care about the values
```

If you favor brevity and/or have a bone to pick with your fellow developers, the `reduce` could be converted to a single expression using spread operators (`...`) and a falsy coalesce (`out[arr[1]] || []`).

```js
const coordinateArray = [[46,11], [38,11], [44,9], [81,15], [55,15]];
const matched = coordinateArray.reduce((out,arr) => ({...out, [arr[1]]: [arr, ...(out[arr[1]] || [])]}), {});
console.log(Object.values(matched));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely better ways to write this with less lines of code posted above, but this might be a little bit easier for you to follow:

```js
const coordinateArray = [[46,11], [38,11], [44,9], [81,15], [55,15]];

const rowArrays = [];

coordinateArray.forEach(c => {
    // set match to false at the beginning of every new coordinate
    let match = false;
    rowArrays.forEach (r => {
      // check if your coordinate lattitude already exists in rowArrays
      // if it does, push it to that array, and set match to true
      if (r[0][1] === c[1]) {
        r.push(c);
        match = true;
      }
    });
    // after iterating through every item in rowArrays, if you still
    // haven't found a match, push the new array to rowArrays.
   if(!match){
    rowArrays.push([c])
   }
  });

console.log(rowArrays)
```